# How to change input values dynamically in selenium webdriver using Java while running the same script multiple times

Tags: java, selenium

Support I have run a script for the fist time to create a group with name 'Selenium Beginners'.

Then again I want to run the same script but now I want to create different group name say 'Selenium Experts' and so on.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone suggest on it.

Comment: Are you sending this group name to any input field? which site are you using for this?

Comment: What did you try already? Please copy your code.

Comment: I am just using sendKeys("Selenium Begineer")

Comment: It is creating fine on first go. Next time it says Group Name already exists. Hence I want logic to make this field dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Store the 'text to send' in a variable and change the value before each run

2.Create a random String and send it each time. For ex

```
element.sendKeys(generateRandomString());


 public String generateRandomString() {
    return "Selenium Beginners" + new BigInteger(120, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
}
```

Comment: Please remove, who ever have given minus to  me. As it allow me to ask questions in future.

Comment: Done @Madhan. Can you please change the minus if you gave to  me as I am completely into manual testing, just now starting implementing selenium web driver.

Comment: @sivasankarraparthi This has nothing to do with me.It's the forum users who thought that it's not a valid question.In the future [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)